# Return two database results with the one jQuery AJAX form (or response)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

## What I have:

I have a form that uses jQuery AJAX to query a database and returns a series of `<option>` elements that are appended to a `<select>` element.

## What I need:

Using the same form, I need to run a second query on a **different** table in the **same** database which will determine which radio button is checked in a radio button group. A URN is sent via AJAX to return which radio button should be selected.

## My code:

**HTML:**

```
<form type="post" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="adddetailstoanexistingclient_form" name="adddetailstoanexistingclient_form">

    <input type="hidden" id="sendingclienturn_js" name="sendingclienturn_js"/>

    <select id="factivity_buildproject_a" name="factivity_buildproject_a">
        <option selected="selected"></option>
        <!--AJAX HTML RESULTS GO HERE-->
        <option value = "Build / Project non-specific">Build / Project non-specific</option>
    </select>

    <input type="radio" name="factivity_prospectstrength" value="1" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="factivity_prospectstrength" value="2" /> 2
    <input type="radio" name="factivity_prospectstrength" value="3" /> 3
    <input type="radio" name="factivity_prospectstrength" value="4" /> 4
    <input type="radio" name="factivity_prospectstrength" value="5" /> 5

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="buildorprojects_ajax"/>

</form>
```

**jQuery/AJAX:**

```
$('#sendingclienturn_js').on('change keyup paste input',ajaxSubmit);            

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var adddetailstoanexistingclient_form = $('#adddetailstoanexistingclient_form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
        data: adddetailstoanexistingclient_form,
        success:function(data){

            if (!$.trim(data)){
            $('#factivity_buildproject_a').hide(); 
            $('[name=factivity_buildproject_ro]').show();
            }
            else{
                $('#factivity_buildproject_a').show(); 
                $('[name=factivity_buildproject_ro]').hide();
            }

            $("#factivity_buildproject_a option.filterable_option").remove();   
            $("#factivity_buildproject_a option:first").after(data);

        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
            alert("There is an error with AJAX!");
        }                   
    }); 

    return false;

}
```

**PHP:**

```
function buildorprojects_ajax(){

    global $wpdb;
    $sendingclienturn_js = $_POST['sendingclienturn_js'];

    $query_buildsorprojects = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM wp_crm_bplist
        WHERE clienturn = '$sendingclienturn_js'
        AND deleted <> '1'
        ORDER BY buildorproject, recorddateandtime DESC
        "
    );

    if($query_buildsorprojects===FALSE){
        echo "Error";  
    }
    else {
        foreach ( $query_buildsorprojects as $query_buildorproject ) {
            echo '<option class="filterable_option" value="'.$query_buildorproject->recordurn.'"  data-clienturn="'.$query_buildorproject->clienturn.'">'.$query_buildorproject->buildprojecturn.' - '.$query_buildorproject->buildorproject.' ('.$query_buildorproject->buildorprojecttype.')</option>';
        }   

    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_buildorprojects_ajax', 'buildorprojects_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_buildorprojects_ajax', 'buildorprojects_ajax');
```

## What I've tried:

I've duplicated the above code (HTML, jQuery AJAX and PHP), changing the necessary titles of ids, names, functions and variables which works but at the cost of my first AJAX function failing.

I've deduced that the problem occurs when adding the second hidden field to my HTML code. The second AJAX form submission breaks the first.

i.e.

**Works with one hidden field:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="buildorprojects_ajax"/>
```

**Does not work with second hidden field:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="buildorprojects_ajax"/>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="prospectstrength_ajax"/>
```

Comment: PHP does how you command it. For example, when you say it should `die();` it *will* die. You're in control. You're the commander. http://php.net/die

Comment: I added my second database query before die(); which indeed works but both results are now merged together as the one string. I've tried returning/passing the data as an array (http://pastebin.com/f15h0R2E) but a value of 0 is produced.

Comment: One request = one response. One response = one string (response body). You're in control. You're the commander. The computer does like you command it.

Comment: I'm unable to intuit any approaches beyond **1)** Two individual requests and two individual PHP functions (**as in the code in my question**) thereby producing 1 response and **2)** One request and one individual PHP function (**as in the Pastebin code in my penultimate comment**) thereby producing 1 response. The best I can hope to achieve with either of these approaches is to apply `.substr()` to the one response.

Comment: yes, you can encode two segments into one response. All you then need to do is to decode the response into two segments. This *could* be done with substr, but as this is AJAX, you're perhaps just looking to create an array and json_encode it, so you've to two strings after json decoding.

Comment: As instructed, I created the array and applied json_encode to it. I then separated the 2 responses into variables using JSON.parse. Thank you for breaking the process down. The relevant code: http://pastebin.com/vwkYxLKJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can encode two segments into one response. All you then need to do is to decode the response into two segments. This could be done with substr, but as this is AJAX, you're perhaps just looking to create an array and json_encode it, so you've to two strings after json decoding.

## Alternatively:

If you want to share the same response with multiple segments of data you want to pass along, you can create multiple segments with the help of JSON and PHP's global static state.

JSON should be handy because most AJAX javascript routines offer to parse it directly.

Global static static on the other hand is used big time in Wordpress, so you won't break with that.

For example at different places you could add to the response:

```
function ajax_callback_red() {
    ...
    JsonResponse::add('<options/>');
}

function ajax_callback_green() {
    ...
    JsonResponse::add('<checkboxes/>');
}
```

When the request finishes, that `JsonResponse` (here statically accessed) the can turn such into JSON:

```
[
    "<options\/>",
    "<checkboxes\/>"
]
```

Such code can be quickly written. Either with a class destructor or you register some shutdown action:

```
class JsonResponse
{
    static $instance;

    private $segments = array();

    /**
     * conditionally assign class instance to global variable and
     * return it.
     *
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        self::$instance || self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function add($segment) {
        self::getInstance()->addSegment($segment);
    }

    public function addSegment($segment) {
        $this->segments[] = $segment;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        echo json_encode($this->segments, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        die();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've opted for the JSON encoding/decoding approach which has yielded a successful result. In acknowledgement of the second approach you've outlined, the positioning of the provided code is ambiguous to me.

Comment: @ClarusDignus: I did understood your question that you would like to call two ajax action callbacks within one request - but sometimes only one of them. The helper class I've in the answer is for exactly that: To share the same output channel (with segments) across multiple ajax callbacks. As you can return both in one (you call json_encode your own), it's just not needed (and therefore you shouldn't use that class). Apart from that, the main idea was about using json, the code just exemplary.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of setting the action with hidden fields is flawed. If you need to run two queries on each change, keyup, paste, or input, then try something like

```
$('#sendingclienturn_js').on('change keyup paste input',function(){
    ajaxSubmit('buildorprojects');
    ajaxSubmit('prospectstrength');
});

function ajaxSubmit(action){
    type:"POST",
    url: "admin-ajax.php?action="+action,
    data: [pull in the correct data for the action],
```

Better yet, if these two requests are always done together, you really need only one request and for your PHP to run the two actions and return a single object. Like Hakre says in his comment, you have the power, use it.

Comment: Using Hakre's instructions, I was able to successfully utilise one request, as you mentioned. I attempted applying your reccoemded ammendments by deleting the name attributes for the hidden fields, editing the on change function and the url value for the ajaxSubmit function (http://pastebin.com/kgmUbxmq). This does not work on my end.

Comment: The use of the hidden fields, based on [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)  tutorial, may in some way be specific to WordPress AJAX use. The value of the hidden fields must correspond to the name of the function/hook/action in the functions.php file of the WordPress theme.